# Differentiation product of functions in multidimensional Analysis

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> Define $k: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ such that $ k(x)=g(x)f(x)^T$, where $f: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^m, g: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^m$ are differentiable functions. Prove that $k$ is differentiable and apply for $v,x\in \mathbb{R}^d$:
>   $$k'(x)v=\left(\sum\limits_{l=1}^d\big(v_l f_i(x) \partial_l g_i(x)+v_lg_i(x)\partial_lf_j(x)\big)\right)_{i,j=1,...m} \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$$

First I thought I have to differentiate partial, but I'm not sure how to deal with $g(x)^T$. Then I want to derivate directional to vector $v$, but there is the same problem.
Some ideas or hints?

Comment: Any idea for this Problem?

Comment: what are $f$ and $g$? Are you assuming that they are both differentiable?

Comment: Yes, they are differentiable!

Comment: Alright then see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that $f: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^m$, $g: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^m$ are differentiable, the fact that $k$ is differentiable follows from Theorem 7 on p. 7 [here](http://individual.utoronto.ca/jordanbell/notes/frechetderivatives.pdf) applied to each component of $g$ multiplied with $f^T$, and then the fact showing differentiability for each component of $gf^T$ suffices to show the differentiability of $k=gf^T$ itself follows from Theorem 4.3 on p. 5 [here](http://math.colorado.edu/~nita/Differentiability2.pdf) (the whole document looks like a good refresher on total derivatives in general).

This result also gives us a formula for calculating the derivative of $k=gf^T$: $$Dk(x)=D(g \cdot f^T)(x)= Dg(x)\cdot f^T(x)+g(x)\cdot (Df(x))^T$$

By using the definitions, you should get the desired expression when evaluating $$k'(x)(v) = Dk(x)(v)= \left[ D(g \cdot f^T)(x) \right](v) = \left[Dg(x) \cdot f^T(x)\right](v) + \left[g(x) \cdot (Df(x))^T\right](v)$$

I would go into more detail, but you said you were looking primarily for ideas/hints.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The first formula you mentioned is the product rule isn't it? So I get this: $$k'(x)=(g'(x)f(x)^T)(v)+(g(x)f'(x)^T)(v)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^d (\partial g_i(x)f_i(x)^Tv_i)+(g_i(x)f_i(x)^Tv_i)$$ I dont know how to handle with the transposed $f_i(x)^T$.

Comment: Do you know the definition of inner/scalar/dot product? That's all multiplying a column vector by a row vector is-- the dot product. So I believe the $(i,j)$-th entry of $k'(x)$ should be $ (\partial g_i(x) f_j(x) )+(g_i(x)\partial f_j(x))$. Also note to not confuse $k'(x)$ and $k'(x)v$.

Comment: Yes, I know it. Thanks for your correcting. So I get: $$k'(x)v=\sum\limits_{i=1}^d (\partial g_i(x)f_j(x)v_i)+(g_i(x)\partial f_j(x)v_i)$$

Comment: Wouldn't the summation be over $l$ instead of $i$? Otherwise it looks good

Comment: Yes you are right, I swapped the summation index!